# How to run Tornado IO Loop during Behave environment setup

Tags: python, bdd, tornado

In a project I'm working in I need to cover a [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) service with [Behave](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/) so I want to start an instance of my tornado service before running each scenario.

Naively trying to run the loop as part before all seems to lock the excecution:

```
from tornado import ioloop
from tornadoadapter.applications import APPLICATION


def before_all(context):
    print "Service running on port 8000"
    APPLICATION.listen(8000)
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

So it's probably not what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your IOLoop is running in the main thread, so it's blocking. You could do it in a separate thread or process.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

from tornado import ioloop
from tornadoadapter.applications import APPLICATION


def run_server():
    print "Service running on port 8000"
    APPLICATION.listen(8000)
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()


def before_all(context):
    context.server_thread = Process(target=run_server)
    context.server_thread.deamon = True
    context.server_thread.start()
```

Comment: When I try to run this on Windows, I get the following exception: `pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function run_server at 0x000000000376B358>: it's not found as __main__.run_server`

Comment: sounds like your `run_server` function is not picklable. quick thing to check is if you can actually import `run_server`? i.e. if it's a lambda or an inner function to `before_all` it won't work.

Comment: `run_server` is defined just as it is in your code sample; it's in the same file, right before `before_all` is defined.